How to get neural processing unit (NPU)'s information by C#
I am working on C# WPF, and I want to get NPU's information (like capable of performing 40+ trillion operations pers second (TOPS)).
I am also using WMI command to get my CPU info like Caption and Manufacturer.
ManagementObjectSearcher search1 = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_Processor");
But it's seem WMI doesn't have command for get NPU information yet.
Is there any chance that I could get those information from my PC by C# WPF?
Thanks for reading and appreciate for your effort and time to help!

I would first use the (software) tools that came with my processor. Then I could come up with my own "relative factors" moving forward. Everything is easier once there is a standard / base to work from. Then you can communicate in terms of faster or slower; instead of abstractions.
